# Mail Attachment Not Being Sent from iOS App that has been in App Store for Over a Year

Tags: ios, email, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an iOS app that has been in the app store for over a year.  The most recent version was posted April 17.  The purpose of this app is to allow the user to create a chess portable game notation (PGN) file and email it from their iPhone or iPad to their desktop computer.  Then the email attachment can be read by any number of chess database applications.

Within the last week I have had two users give me feedback that the attachment is not included in their emails.  One has shown me a screenshot of the mail composer showing that it is composed with the attachment.

Not being able to send the PGN attachment is a serious issue for this app, so if it was a widespread problem, I would hear from more than two users.

One of the users is sending to a gmail account, the other to an iCloud account.  One user reported that a friend using the same WiFi connection was able to send the email attachment without issues from his iPad. He has also been able to send screen shots and reply to messages from me where I have attached PGN  (mimeType:@"text/pgn") files.

My mail composer code is from Apple examples and has worked for over a year for users all over the world.

Has anyone had a similar experience?  I'm concerned that I have had two issues within a week on code that has been in the app for over a year.

Thanks!

Attached is some of the code to add the attachment data.
Note that the attachment is not a "file".

```
PgnGenerator *generator = [[PgnGenerator alloc] init];
generator.game = inGame;

NSString *pgn = [generator pgnString];

NSData *myData = [pgn dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pgn", [inGame eventAndRound]];

[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/pgn" fileName:fileName];
```

---

Using

```
NSData *myData = [pgn dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

Solved the issue.
"For example, in converting a character from NSUnicodeStringEncoding to NSASCIIStringEncoding, the character ‘Á’ becomes ‘A’, losing the accent."

Many of the chess applications that would be reading the PGN file cannot handle the accented characters anyhow, so losing the accent is is the best solution until the specification is updated.

Comment: Probably worth getting information such as iOS version and exact device from the user, also worth check if they can send attachments in any other way external to your app (if you havent already)

Comment: Could the user pick an illegal file name?

Comment: The iOS version version is the 6.1.3 (10B329) for an iPhone 4 for one. The other user is using iOS 7 on an iPhone.

Comment: RE:Could the user pick an illegal file name.  The file name "Round 1-Entrenamiento", from the chess "event" name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed before that even if the file I'm attaching doesn't exist on the device the mail composer will still show as if the file is going to attach. Then when the email gets sent the attachment is not there.

Is it possible that this situation is occurring?

Comment: Since you asked, I have added the attachment code that shows I am using addAttachmentData for an NSData object.  The body of the email contains a valid chess game so I am sure that there is something in the NSData.  Thanks!

Comment: The issue was found to be with the dataUsingEncoding method.  The PGN specification calls for ISO 8859/1 so I was using NSASCIIStringEncoding.  This was OK until someone entered PGN header information with an accented character, é, å, ...  So a character that is not ASCII causes this method to return nil.  All I had to do was use the allowLossyConversion version of this method to convert the non-ASCII characters.  So, as Brandon said, the mail composer does show the attachment icon even if the data is nil and nothing will be sent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I used NSASCIIStringEncoding NSString was returning nil on iOS7 (it works good on iOS6), NSUTF8StringEncoding works fine

Comment: I just finished moving my CalcFxC app to iOS 7 and there were a lot of things that have worked since iOS 4 that no longer worked.  Many to do with text and UITextView.